# C# binary search, different object types

Tags: c#

I'm making a small game in C#. In it, I have Keyframe objects, each with a specific time that they occur at, in a sorted list. I wish to find the one that occurs after a specific time. Without making a new keyframe object, then searching through the list for that object, ~ing the result and then using that object, is there a syntactically *neat* way to perform the search?

For example:

```
double time = 10.0;
Keyframe blah = new Keyframe(time);
int index = _keyframes.BinarySearch(null, blah);
if (index < 0) index = ~index;
if (index >= _keyframes.Length) return null;
return _keyframes[index];
```

works but involves creation of a new Keyframe object.

Anyone got a concise way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement your own method to do that.  Something like the following:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TList BinaryFind<TList>(this IList<TList> list, Func<TList, int> comparer)
    {
        if (!list.Any())
            return default(TList);

        int pivot = list.Count()/2;
        TList pivotVal = list[pivot];
        int conditionResult = condition(pivotVal);
        if (conditionResult == 0) 
            return pivotVal;
        else
        {
            if (conditionResult < 0) 
                return BinaryFind<TList, TSearchArg>(list.Take(pivot).ToList(), condition);
            else
                return BinaryFind<TList, TSearchArg>(list.Skip(pivot).ToList(), condition);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'd use it something like

```
Keyframe result = _keyframes.BinaryFind(k => Double.Compare(k.Time, time));
```

Comment: It's a bit inefficient due to the use of .ToList(), but thanks anyway.

Comment: @AStupidNoob if you can afford to covert to an array, you can use `Array.ConstrainedCopy` instead of the linq partitioning.  It'd be something like `Array.ConstrainedCopy(list, 0, arr, 0, pivot);` and `Array.ConstrainedCopy(list, pivot+1, arr, 0, pivot);`

Comment: Although you might need to watch for the second throwing InvalidArgumentExceptions.  I can't quite wrap my head around when it'd happen at the moment.

Comment: I didn't know about Array.ConstrainedCopy! Neat! Still, I think the most efficient way would be to pass a start and end parameter to the BinaryFind function. This way, we don't need to make any arrays or allocations at all, we just do stuff on the big array between those spots.

Comment: Quite probably, my background with languages in which partitioning is cheap is showing.

Answer (score 0):

No Way into .net implementation , BinarySearch requires you to pass a object to search , either write a your own implementation.